# What is Sonic the Hedgehog's maximum running speed?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

This question isn't exactly limited to the video game (there's also the Archie Comics books and a TV series), but was there ever a canon answer on how fast Sonic can run?  In his Super Sonic or Hyper Sonic states? I suppose one would have to assume he's running on a flat surface.

Comment: Supersonic and Hypersonic are imprecise terms. Supersonic means "above sonic" and "hypersonic" is a subset of supersonic meaning "highly supersonic". Generally hypersonic *generally* refers to speeds above Mach 5. Like these terms, Sonic's speed is never called out as an exact quantity of distance per time, rather that "he is faster than the speed of sound". Anything more specific than this is not quoted.

Comment: Actually, Super Sonic and Hyper Sonic are states of being for STH when when he has all 7 chaos emeralds and super emeralds respectively.  Think of if as super sayin levels 1 and 2 from the Dragon Ball Z series.

Comment: I realize this, but they are also references to particular velocities, this is what the names are based on (why he goes super and hyper sonic instead of mega and ultra). Quoted speed references are only as specific as "faster than sound".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This wiki answer ["How fast does sonic run in full speed"](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_fast_does_sonic_run_in_full_speed) lists Sonic's increased speeds as he evolved through the games and shows.

- Originally he was said to be the speed of sound, at 767+ miles per hour at sea level.
- In Sonic Unleaded the check points would report his speed in excess of 2500 miles an hour.
- The Sonic Adventure DX manual lists him at least as fast as 3840 miles an hour (hypersonic)
- After that he developed light speed attacks and the ability to travel at light speed and to freeze time.

Like most super powered characters, his powers keep expanding to extend the story. Soon he will be able to transcend both time and space.

Comment: Sonic can go 2,500+ mph by only using *unleaded*? Imagine if he used *premium*!

Answer (score 10):

Officially, and technically, Sonic can run briefly at light speed, with the use of the **Light Speed Dash** power (which itself requires the **Light Speed Shoes**).

This screencap is from Sonic Adventure 1.

[image: Check out Sonic's kicks]

For purposes of game play, Sonic's movement at this speed is not accurately depicted in the games.

Comment: Well, no; at 25–30 fps, it wouldn’t be, wouldn’t it? He’d be on the other side of the globe by the next frame. [Edit: That was just a random, flippant way of phrasing it, but doing a tiny bit of math, it’s actually fairly accurate: at 25 fps, the speed of light would take you about 12,000 km in one frame, which is enough to get you from LA to Sydney, so pretty much halfway around the world.]

Answer (score 0):

Well in Sonic Unleashed through checkpoints he clocked in a speed of 2887 miles per hour or so but further increased to 3000 miles per hour. Sonic has limits but will break them as he gets through new stories.

Answer (score 0):

Within the game his max speed has been as slow as 10 meters per second and less than a quarter the speed of sound but tht's his actual speed in the game according to screw attack

Comment: where does this data come from?

Answer (score -3):

Okay Sonic basically has no limits to his speed but it is recorded his average speed is 767 miles per hour, this means he can break the sound barrier in mere seconds, but it was mentioned sonic can go light speed confirmed by the creator of Sonic, but this drains alot of chaos energy, but Sonic's speed can be affected by some environments like icy areas and muddy areas as well, but he is fast enough to run on water due to his speed and weight, lastly his speed is unknown but it is definetly faster than sound he will increase his speed in future adventures and stories

Comment: Can you add references?

Answer (score -4):

In Sonic Unleashed Sonic the Hedgehog clocked through the check point of 2887 miles per hour, which means this would be 4646.2 kilometers per hour but Sonic can further increase his speed to 3000 miles per hour with his figure 8 technique and spin dash, this would be approximately be 4828 kilometers per, this incredible speed would equal to 1341 meters per second.

Sonic's speed is unknown but clocked in an average of 765 miles per hour as Sonic goes through more adventures his speed would increase greatly. He has no limits to his speed therefore this can be a possibility or fact, Although with all chaos emeralds to summon the form of Super Sonic, this form is a 1000% power increase so if we calculate his speed: 1000*4828= 4 828 000 kilometers per hour in flight mode it would increase approximately 5 000 000 kilometers per hour and compare to the speed of light (1.07925285*10 to the power of 9) this means Super Sonic can nearly reach the speed of light at full top speed and hyper form is 2000% increase and his most powerful form hyper shadic, 1 trillion% this means its 482800000000000000000000 kilometers per hour/compare to the speed of light 1079252850 kilometers per hour this means **HYPER SHADIC is 44 734 417.2 times faster than light**.

This proves that Sonic the Hedgehog is THE FASTEST THING IN LIFE!!!!!!

(I can't comment, so I'll edit the answer instead. This guy made a fatal mistake calculating sonics speed. While he was right at first, he didn't factor in the 1000% speed increase from super form correctly. He multiplied his base speed by 1000, when a 1000% increase is only a mere 10 times his original max speed. That means his max speed in super form is actually only 48280 kilometers per hour. Otherwise, it was a passable theory. Thank you for your time.)

Comment: Where are all these numbers coming from?