# What's the farthest distance Sonic the Hedgehog has ever run?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

We all know Sonic is [fast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18685/75000), but does he have the *stamina* to keep up his speed for extended periods of time? **What's the farthest he's run in a single sprint?** He doesn't need to be using his max speed, but should at least be going "Sonic fast" (ie. no jogging), and not using any special tech other than his normal running shoes.

Answers from the games, shows, and comics are all acceptable.

Comment: If gameplay is included, then he can run indefinitely. In particular, I remember a blue spheres level (probably played it on Mega Collection) where you could go around the checkered sphere in a straight line without needing to turn or jump (a level with the same principal can be found [here](https://bsgen-old.neocities.org/?act=onelevel&val=66249526) I think). Thus leaving the game alone on such a stage would allow Sonic to run forever. I'm sure there are other games where something similar happens but that's what came to my mind.

Comment: @Laurel I'm not asking how far he **can** run, I'm asking how far he **has** run. I can see where you got that idea though.

Answer (score 6):

If I remember correctly, there is a story in one of the Fleetway STC strips where Dr Robotnik lures Sonic to one side of Mobius, then fires an orbital laser at the other. Sonic makes it back to the other side of the planet to foil his plan to vaporize the Green Hill Zone in about 8 seconds.

EDIT - for clarity, it is issue 11, Robotnik targets the Emerald Hill Zone, and Sonic has to make it in 5 seconds. He manages it in 4 and a half.

Comment: That's a nice find. If you have access to some of the panels, please [edit] them into your answer to improve your post :)

Comment: Also, if you have the dimensions of Mobius, that'd be nice too. :)

Answer (score 1):

There was an episode of Sonic X where he couldn't stop running the furthest he ran in that day is 69336 miles but that was when he didn't have control of his feet as a part of one of eggmans robots fell into his ear and for some reason controlled his feet I dont think he could normally have that much stamina outside the games

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was how _far_, not how long.  Can you put some numbers to that?

Comment: Of course this is speculation but to find out that in a day non stop running he can run 69336 miles I found out his max speed is 2889 mph and multiplied it by 24

Comment: You should [edit] that into your answer instead of burying it in the comments where fewer people will see it (and it could get deleted).

Comment: Thank you FreeMan